# REST api postquery with SortList not working

Tags: 2013, search, rest, sorting

I'm using jQuery ajax POST calls to query against my search index. That is working. I tried to add **SortList** following the [documented model here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx#bk_SortList) which is basically adding the following to my query payload

```
'SortList' : {
  'results' : [
    {'Property':'RefinableDecimal00','Direction': '0'},
    {'Property':'Filename','Direction': '0'}
  ]
}
```

**Bonus question** The documentation doesn't say whether 0 is ascending or descending. I assume descending, but not sure. Anybody?

When I add that my query gives me *400 Bad Request Invalid parameter: SortList* error.

Any idea how to sort search results from REST api?

Comment: have you tried running it through the SearchQueryTool? http://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Comment: Looks like that doesn't run client side and we have managed workstations so I don't think I can install it. But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [a tutorial](https://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2014/10/15/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-search-using-http-post/) yesterday that had one sort term in the post query. It took a bit of work to figure out how to do multiple terms. Here is what ended up working for me:

```
'SortList' : {
  'results' : [
    {'__metadata':{'type':'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.Sort'},
        'Property':RefinableDecimal00,'Direction':0
    },
    {'__metadata':{'type':'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.Sort'},
    'Property':FileName,'Direction':0
    }
  ]
}
```

BTW 0 = ascending and 1 = descending